# When is it true that $a^{n}<n!$?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, axioms

How can I  find the smaller $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which makes the equation true: $$a^{n}<n!$$

For example:

If $a=2$ then $\longrightarrow 2^{n}<n!$ when $n\geq 4$

If $a=3$ then $\longrightarrow 3^{n}<n!$ when $n\geq 7$

If $a=4$ then $\longrightarrow 4^{n}<n!$ when $n\geq 9$

If $a=5$ then $\longrightarrow 5^{n}<n!$ when $n\geq 12$

$$a,n\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$a^{n}<n!$$when$$n\geq ?$$

Comment: Do you want to find the least $n$, or just _some_ $n$?

Comment: I want to find the smaller $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , which makes the equation true.

Comment: Can't believe nobody mentioned https://oeis.org/A086824.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $n!\approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt {2\pi n}$ (Stirling), we have $a^n\approx n!$ when $a\approx \frac ne\,\sqrt[2n]{2\pi n}$. Hence $$n=\lceil ea\rceil$$ should be good enough. Note that this gives $n=6$ for $a=2$, $n=9$ for $a=3$, $n=11$ for $a=4$, $n=14$ for $a=5$, so is just mildly subobtimal.

Comment: Since Stirling's underestimates $n!$, you might get away with floors indtead of ceilings...

Answer (score 0):

I find a equation:

> $$ a^{n}<n! \Longleftrightarrow n \geq  (2a)+\lfloor\frac{(a-1)}{2}\rfloor$$

Comment: This pattern doesn't hold for large $a$--as Hagen von Eitzen's answer indicates, you need $n$ to be about $ea$.

Comment: sorry .. $2*10+\lfloor \frac{(10-1)}{2}\rfloor = 25$

Comment: Sorry again!! the ecuation is -> $n \geq  (2a)+\lfloor\frac{(a-1)}{2}\rfloor -1 $

Comment: $75^{186}\approx 5.7\times10^{348} > 7.7\times 10^{342} \approx 186!$. $(2\times75)+\lfloor\frac{75-1}{2}\rfloor-1=186$. Plus, $24$ is wrong for $10$, it should be $25$.

Comment: You are right !! 
 the ecuation doesn't hold for large  :(